# for what do i need the Error porperty in IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just implement the `IDataErrorInfo` and I always wonder why `public string Error => null;` is neccesary for the interface.

I implement it as following:

```
    //this works fine
    public string this[string propertyName] => propertyName switch
    {
        //do my check
        nameof(my property) => thing i want to validate ? error message : nothing
    }

    //what to do with this?
    //0 references 
    public string Error => null;
```

Can anybody explain me please why do I need it, or why does it even exist?

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this[]` indexer property lists the errors **per property**.

`string Error` is "An error message indicating what is wrong with this object".

So it is for any problem that is not directly related to a specific property.
It is used far less often, returning `null` is customary.

Answer (score 2):

[MS Spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
says it "Gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object."  I can't see anything in WPF or MVC 4.X that actually uses it automatically.  But you could have a summary string that would have to be manually retrieved and displayed.

see below

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="validationTooltip" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="asterisk" BasedOn="{StaticResource validationTooltip}" >
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" >
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="16pt" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,10,0" FontWeight="Bold">*</TextBlock>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Margin="6" 
                ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="grdData">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource asterisk}" Width="550" Height="44" Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Error, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="122,257,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            var item= new MyClass() { SomeProperty = "Testing" };

        grdData.DataContext = item;
    }
}
public class MyClass : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string this[string columnName] => "Some Specific Error";

    public string Error => "Something is wrong";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I still can´t get the "Something is wrong" displayed

Comment: The code above is from a quick example app and it displays the "Something is wrong".  You have to create a textblock or some other control to show the value of this property.   Done here....-> <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Error, Mode=OneWay}"...